# Magento Autoload.php on line 93 Error

Tags: php, magento

I get below error in magento system.log and file is getting bigger and bigger.

```
2013-11-23T17:30:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/jebra/public_html/lib/google/google-api-php-client:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jebra/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-11-23T17:30:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/jebra/public_html/lib/google/google-api-php-client:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jebra/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/jebra/public_html/lib/google/google-api-php-client:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jebra/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/jebra/public_html/lib/google/google-api-php-client:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jebra/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-11-23T17:30:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2013-11-23T17:30:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/jebra/public_html/lib/google/google-api-php-client:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jebra/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jebra/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/jebra/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is trying to use a helper from Magento Enterprise and you probably only have Magento Community installed.

This might be due to an extension that checks for `class_exists()` because the Magento autoloader always tries to include a file even if it does not exists and then fails with a warning, rendering `class_exists()` useless.

Search your codebase for the class name `Enterprise_Cms_Helper_Data` and remove any reference to it.